# Adding a CheckboxColumn to SPDataGridView

Tags: spgridview

I wish to add one column which has a unchecked checkbox in it. This is used so the user can select multiple rows.

```
datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Selected", typeof(bool)));
```

if above datatable is used in a normal DataGridView it shows a checkbox instead of a bool. However when used in a SPGridView it will just show me true/false.

```
datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Selected", typeof(CheckBox)));
```

Above datatable shows System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox instead of the checkbox or the true/false value.

So how van i create a column which only shows a checkbox in each row. And how can i add a CheckBox to the column header so the user can select that one for all rows in the SpGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check link below. It Shows How to add Check box in SPGridView.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/adding-checkboxes-in-sharepoint-gridview-spgridview/

and check this link which shows that how to add header Check box  in SpGridView.

[CheckBox header to select all checkBoxes in SPGridView](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41522/checkbox-header-to-select-all-checkboxes-in-spgridview)